# Regex takes a long time to complete

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wanted to match a line that is structured like this:

- Start of line
- Multiple '-'
- Maybe a white space (maybe more)
- At least one character
- Maybe more characters and white spaces
- Maybe a white space (maybe more)
- Multiple '-'
- End of line

So I wrote the Regex like this:

```
new Regex(@"^\-{2,}\s*(\w+(\w+|\s)*)\s*\-{2,}$");
```

And when I try to match the following line, this takes ages to complete (didn't wait for it to complete):

```
-------- Variable used for recipe visualization only - Not loaded into PLC --------
```

I think there's a very big number of matches in it and the Regex have hard time enumerating all those matches but I'm not sure.

Environment information: Windows 7, framework 3.5

Thank you

**Edit:** Thanks to your help I came up with a Regex that works:

```
^-{2,}\s*(?!\-)(\w(?:\w|\s|\-)+)(?<!\-)\s*-{2,}$
```

So the interpretation:

- Start of line
- At least two '-'
- Maybe a white space (maybe more)
- No more '-'
- At least one character
- Maybe more characters, white spaces or '-'
- No more '-'
- Maybe a white space (maybe more)
- At least two '-'
- End of line

If you see something wrong with it please tell me

Comment: That's not going to match because of the internal dash in "only - Not".

Comment: your problem is you aren't allowing the ` - ` in the middle to be captured

Comment: I just tried this on https://myregextester.com/index.php and it ran in 0.018301 seconds.  But it does take an extremely long time to run in C#, but removing that internal dash really speeds it up.

Comment: @juharr and Jonesopolis thank you for your answers. But why can't it just return false instead of running for a long time?

Comment: @juharr thank you for testing it

Comment: I'd  expect this part to be responsible: `(\w+(\w+|\s)*)`. Basically you allow for any partition of a sequence of words and spaces as long as a sequence of spaces is left intact. Since the whole expression does not match, backtracking will visit all of the admissible partitions in turn. Try to replace it with `(\w+(\s+\w+)*)`.

Comment: Thank you all for explaining the problem. I'll fix that

Comment: @juharr Edited the question to include the regex I came up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unroll the nested grouping as

```
^-{2,}\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*-{2,}$
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, your pattern will be prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH4uS3/1)

Alternatively, use an atomic group to disable any backtracking into the alternation group:

```
^-{2,}\s*((?>\w+(?:\w+|\s)*))\s*-{2,}$
          ^^^              ^
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E-%7B2%2C%7D%5Cs*((%3F%3E%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cs)*))%5Cs*-%7B2%2C%7D%24&i=--------%20Variable%20used%20for%20recipe%20visualization%20only%20-%20Not%20loaded%20into%20PLC%20--------)

Generally, avoid alternations with nested quantifiers (like in `(\w+|\s)*`) inside longer patterns.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a Regex that works for this case. Could you take a look and tell me if something could be wrong with it? Thank you

Comment: The regex is not optimal. `(?!-)` is totally redundant since the next subpattern is `\w` and thus the lookahead check result is always *true*. I'd rewrite as `^-{2,}\s*(\w+(?:[\s-]+\w+)*)\s*-{2,}$` (the `(?<!-)` is not necessary then since the only possible character before the last optional whitespace and hyphens can be a word character. Note that `-` does not have to be escaped outside the character class.